# Java SplitPaneDemo not working?

Tags: java, jsplitpane

I am trying to get this up code up and running from java official site but I am getting

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Native Method)
    at sun.awt.Win32GraphicsConfig.getBounds(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.init(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Frame.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(Unknown Source)
```

http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/SplitPaneDemo2Project/src/components/SplitPaneDemo2.java

Also, at the following line, the method doesn't even exist. I am using `getContentPane()` instead.

```
 JSplitPane top = splitPaneDemo.getSplitPane();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The demo works just fine. It's your modification(s) that don't work :)

This *does* work:

```
/*
 * Copyright (c) 1995, 2008, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
 *
 * Redistribution and use in source and binary forms, with or without
 * modification, are permitted provided that the following conditions
 * are met:
 *
 *   - Redistributions of source code must retain the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer.
 *
 *   - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright
 *     notice, this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the
 *     documentation and/or other materials provided with the distribution.
 *
 *   - Neither the name of Oracle or the names of its
 *     contributors may be used to endorse or promote products derived
 *     from this software without specific prior written permission.
 *
 * THIS SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED BY THE COPYRIGHT HOLDERS AND CONTRIBUTORS "AS
 * IS" AND ANY EXPRESS OR IMPLIED WARRANTIES, INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * THE IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR
 * PURPOSE ARE DISCLAIMED.  IN NO EVENT SHALL THE COPYRIGHT OWNER OR
 * CONTRIBUTORS BE LIABLE FOR ANY DIRECT, INDIRECT, INCIDENTAL, SPECIAL,
 * EXEMPLARY, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES (INCLUDING, BUT NOT LIMITED TO,
 * PROCUREMENT OF SUBSTITUTE GOODS OR SERVICES; LOSS OF USE, DATA, OR
 * PROFITS; OR BUSINESS INTERRUPTION) HOWEVER CAUSED AND ON ANY THEORY OF
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN CONTRACT, STRICT LIABILITY, OR TORT (INCLUDING
 * NEGLIGENCE OR OTHERWISE) ARISING IN ANY WAY OUT OF THE USE OF THIS
 * SOFTWARE, EVEN IF ADVISED OF THE POSSIBILITY OF SUCH DAMAGE.
 */ 
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class SplitPaneDemo2 extends JFrame
        implements ListSelectionListener {

    private JLabel label;

    public SplitPaneDemo2() {
        super("SplitPaneDemo2");

        //Create an instance of SplitPaneDemo
        SplitPaneDemo splitPaneDemo = new SplitPaneDemo();
        JSplitPane top = splitPaneDemo.getSplitPane();
        splitPaneDemo.getImageList().addListSelectionListener(this);

        //XXXX: Bug #4131528, borders on nested split panes accumulate.
        //Workaround: Set the border on any split pane within
        //another split pane to null. Components within nested split
        //panes need to have their own border for this to work well.
        top.setBorder(null);

        //Create a regular old label
        label = new JLabel("Click on an image name in the list.",
                JLabel.CENTER);

        //Create a split pane and put "top" (a split pane)
        //and JLabel instance in it.
        JSplitPane splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT,
                top, label);
        splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
        splitPane.setDividerLocation(180);

        //Provide minimum sizes for the two components in the split pane
        top.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 50));
        label.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 30));

        //Add the split pane to this frame
        getContentPane().add(splitPane);
    }

    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        if (e.getValueIsAdjusting())
            return;

        JList theList = (JList) e.getSource();
        if (theList.isSelectionEmpty()) {
            label.setText("Nothing selected.");
        } else {
            int index = theList.getSelectedIndex();
            label.setText("Selected image number " + index);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new SplitPaneDemo2();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

class SplitPaneDemo extends JPanel
        implements ListSelectionListener {
    private JLabel picture;
    private JList list;
    private JSplitPane splitPane;
    private String[] imageNames = {"Bird", "Cat", "Dog", "Rabbit", "Pig", "dukeWaveRed",
            "kathyCosmo", "lainesTongue", "left", "middle", "right", "stickerface"};

    public SplitPaneDemo() {

        //Create the list of images and put it in a scroll pane.

        list = new JList(imageNames);
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        list.setSelectedIndex(0);
        list.addListSelectionListener(this);


        JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
        picture = new JLabel();
        picture.setFont(picture.getFont().deriveFont(Font.ITALIC));
        picture.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);

        JScrollPane pictureScrollPane = new JScrollPane(picture);

        //Create a split pane with the two scroll panes in it.
        splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT,
                listScrollPane, pictureScrollPane);
        splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
        splitPane.setDividerLocation(150);

        //Provide minimum sizes for the two components in the split pane.
        Dimension minimumSize = new Dimension(100, 50);
        listScrollPane.setMinimumSize(minimumSize);
        pictureScrollPane.setMinimumSize(minimumSize);

        //Provide a preferred size for the split pane.
        splitPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 200));
        updateLabel(imageNames[list.getSelectedIndex()]);
    }

    //Listens to the list
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        JList list = (JList) e.getSource();
        updateLabel(imageNames[list.getSelectedIndex()]);
    }

    //Renders the selected image
    protected void updateLabel(String name) {
        ImageIcon icon = createImageIcon("images/" + name + ".gif");
        picture.setIcon(icon);
        if (icon != null) {
            picture.setText(null);
        } else {
            picture.setText("Image not found");
        }
    }

    //Used by SplitPaneDemo2
    public JList getImageList() {
        return list;
    }

    public JSplitPane getSplitPane() {
        return splitPane;
    }


    /**
     * Returns an ImageIcon, or null if the path was invalid.
     */
    protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) {
        java.net.URL imgURL = SplitPaneDemo.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } else {
            System.err.println("Couldn't find file: " + path);
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event-dispatching thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SplitPaneDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        SplitPaneDemo splitPaneDemo = new SplitPaneDemo();
        frame.getContentPane().add(splitPaneDemo.getSplitPane());

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can stick it all in a file named `SplitPaneDemo2.java` and compile and run it.

Original source:

- [SplitPaneDemo.java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/SplitPaneDemo2Project/src/components/SplitPaneDemo.java)
- [SplitPaneDemo2.java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/SplitPaneDemo2Project/src/components/SplitPaneDemo2.java)

Answer (score 2):

`getContentPane ()` was a former approach. Today you just add a panel to the frame, where you put your stuff.

Comment: Whether or not using `getContentPane()` before adding components would not cause a `StackOverflowError` error though.

Comment: No, my point is that while you're right that `getContentPane()` isn't necessary, it does not help the much by resolving his StackOverflowError. The OP might think that you mean the `getContentPane()` is causing the StackOverflowError, which is not the case.

Comment: Yes, yes, I already agreed on that. I wanted to change the topic to the missing source to find the real bug.

Comment: @Kim, most probably you're making a recursive call somewhere that never ends. Hard to tell without seeing your code.